# When running an executable file with a Python subprocess, can I repeatedly enter the for loop value in the input of the command line?

Tags: python, input, subprocess, executable

I have some problems with subprocess and command line input with for loop.

I have an executable file generated from code written in matlab.

This executable file takes a folder name as an input variable and creates a result file like below.

```
path = r'C:/Users/MyName/python_project/Exe_Running/Folder_A/'
exe_path = r'C:\Users\MyName\python_project\Exe_Running\Folder_A\MyExe.exe'

# all need files and exe file in path folder

# so I use subprocess like below

subprocess.Popen(exe_path, shell=True).communicate()
# or
subprocess.call(exe_path)
# both subprocess function takes me like below command line user input
```

[MY Pycharm command line when run subprocess function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFtP2.png)

So, I input my path('C:/Users/MyName/python_project/Exe_Running/Folder_A/') into command line

Then, IT WORKS WELL and make the file I want.

but, when I use subprocess like below with arguments

```
subprocess.Popen([exe_path, path], shell=True).communicate()
# or
subprocess.call([exe_path, path])
```

Then, it makes error **"Running script as a function is not supported."**

I'm not sure if it's because it's a file written in Matlab or for some other reason. The exe file is an executable file created by a colleague.

I have to run the exe file several times and each time I have to enter a different folder path.

I want to repeat this process through a for loop and enter a different path into the command line each time like below.

```
folder_list = ['Folder_A', 'Folder_B', ..., 'Folder_Z']

for folder in folder_list:
   subprocess.Popen(exe_path, shell=True).communicate()
   # then, command line need user input
   # I want fill user input to use my "folder" value in for loop without directly typing
```

Is there a way to put a for loop variable in user input? (My python version is 3.9)

Thanks for reading.

sincerely.

I want fill user input to use my "folder" value in for loop without directly typing